# Android Module private class / Module Api

Tags: java, android

I'm doing a project with modules in android, and within each module I have sub-packages with their respective entities, repositories, etc. To handle access within this packages, I must use public class, and this gives access to other modules. I need a single class/packages to be used as an API that can be Access from other modules and hides internal implementation.
I'dont know if java allow this? how i can do this?

thanks

Comment: for anyone looking in kotlin. use internal modifier.

Answer (score 0):

> Access from other modules and hides internal implementation

Yep. Extract the API to an interface and then define an implementation of that interface with a visibility modifier lower than that of the public interface. Hide the binding of that interface-to-concrete implementation via an init method of your module. Expose this init method to your module too.

Using dependency injection or a service locator pattern, you can then request the implementation of this interface from your caller modules. Generally, in more complex applications, it's dependency injection you're wanting to use. In this case, a factory method is required to bind between the interface and concrete implementation.

If you are using a dependency injection library with Java then you're likely looking at using an `@Bind`ing and an `@Provides` method to achieve this wiring and provisioning respectively.